# Compile logs from different long paths

Tags: 18.04

I'm fairly new to ubuntu.

I got multiple copies of a program that have the same paths for logs, and I add more as I need. But it is getting tiring to retrieve logs every time I need to check one particular app.

My folder structure looks like this

```
/opt/app1/a/long/path/to/logs/1.log
/opt/app2/a/long/path/to/logs/1.log
/opt/app3/a/long/path/to/logs/1.log
```

What I want to do is,

```
/logs/app1/1.log
/logs/app2/1.log
/logs/app3/1.log
```

I would like to also make it somewhat dynamic, so if I add app4 it will automatically still be copied.

I don't really know how to get this to work even a static one, let alone whenever adding a new one. Not even sure if I want to hard or soft link them, I'd like to get recommendations what to do with it.

TIA

Comment: Seems like your programs are not using the built-in logging tool: `rsyslog`, which would save your logs to /var/log/app_name/log. Look up how to use it.

Comment: I didnt write the app. They are also docker apps.

Comment: Please add that vital information to [your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1243447/edit)! Both of those facts make a huge difference. Is there some reason you cannot simply use symlinks or hardlinks? If so, add that to your question, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a script ?

It's not clear what you want us to do to help you... You could just edit where the logs are saved in your app. You could also make a [SymLink](https://wiki.debian.org/SymLink) (but it sometimes mess the things up...).

For the script, something like :

```bsh
#!bin/bash

read -p "Name App : " app                     # What is "app1, app2, app3...
less /opt/${app}/a/long/path/to/logs/1.log    # Read from log
exit
```

Comment: Thanks, not really sure too what to do to be honest. Bit harder to edit the app itself, since I didnt write it and not sure how will that go.

Also copying the contents might not be an ideal way to do it, the logs are like 100mb each, and I have like 30 instances at times. So it would unnecessarily bloat and use CPU.